# Can I customize the way the mouse moves between monitors?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, mouse, osx-yosemite, synergy

I'm using my Mid-2014 13" MacBook Pro with Retina display along with two 20" external monitors. Both are 1200x1600 rotated to portrait orientation, one on either side of the laptop. The screens are configured using the OS X display layout tool to match their physical layout, shown below:

```
______       ______
|    |       |    |
|    |_______|    |
|    |       |    |
|____|_______|____|
```

Because the laptop display is 2560x1600, on a pixel level, my display is rectangular (4960x1600). However, when moving the mouse between monitors, the motion mimics the physical layout of the monitors, where the short side of the 13" monitor is much shorter than the long side of the 20" monitors next to it. As a result, if I'm moving the mouse from the top of my left monitor to the top of my right monitor, I first have to move it down to where the macbook screen is, then back up again once I've moved over.

I would like to be able to move my mouse around as if the desktop was a 4960x1600 pixel rectangle, preferably without having to make the text on the retina display too small.  I do have good eyes, though, so if the only way to do this is to set the same DPI on the retina display as the 20" monitors will be too small, I'd welcome suggestions as to how to do that.

The other possible solution would be something that would "warp" my mouse between the top right edge of the left monitor and the top left edge of the right monitor, but I think this would be less good.

I have minimal experience with OS X, but lots of experience running desktop linux distros, and configuring the X server to do weird things with multiple monitors. One solution might be to install linux on the MacBook and do it that way.

I assume that there would be some sort of software required, and would welcome recommendations.

Internally, I think that OS X is doing some sort of scaling, so that when moving left from pixel (0,y) on the internal display, it goes to pixel (1200, f*y) on the left display, where f is something like (height of external monitor)/(height of internal monitor). I'd like to force f=1.

When I'm at home, I use Synergy to move seamlessly between my desktop and laptop, and it maps the mouse in the way I'm looking for.